# New headset, cannot find boot option

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a new void headset, but I am having the issue where the driver signature cannot be verified. I tried the general solution which is pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> to disable the signature command in in windows, but my issue is being unable to find the option to disable this command, all I have available to me are the general cpu overclock, monitor things of this nature.

My mother board is the 
ASUSTeK COMPUTER 
Model   M5A97 LE R2.0 (Socket 942)

Comment: Have you tried the second option at http://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-windows-cannot-verify-the-digital-signature-for-this-file-error-in-windows-8-7-vista/ ?

Comment: I have not, that seems to be for windows 8, i am currently on 7 but I will definitely read more into it.

Comment: If you had just read the title, you would know that it applies to Windows 7, 8 and Vista.

Comment: I went through all of it, no matter sold my soul. trying to upgrade to 10 now.